# Php preg_match error message

Tags: php, regex

I want to match a string using REGEX which follows the syntax:

```
Text/number
```

So my `preg_match()` function is...

```
if(preg_match("/[^A-Za-z/0-9]$/ ", $folio))
$err[] = "Wrong value, it's should be lik: C/455";
```

But getting error message...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if ( ! preg_match('/\b[a-z]+\/[0-9]+\b/i', $folio)) {
  $err[] = "Wrong value, it's should be like this: C/455";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$folio = "Text/15";
if(preg_match('~[a-z]/[\d]~i', $folio))
    echo "match";
else
    echo "no match";
```

Comment: i think you need to escape the '/', i.e. replace with //

Comment: @MukeshSoni No, because I use `~` as prefix/suffix

Answer (score 1):

You needed to escape `/` using `\`. Also numbers is a subset of text and you need to include it in your text part. You need one or more text/numeric characters, so a `+` is required.

It adds up to the following statement:

```
if(preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+\/[0-9]+$/", $folio))
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to escape / or use different char to surround regexp, for example:

```
if(preg_match("@[^A-Za-z/0-9]$@ ", $folio))
```